# If/Then/Else in Formatting a Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement

I am trying to get the fiscal period and year out of an invoice date. Using the month() function together with the Case I am able to get the period. since Period 1 is in November I need to do a +1 1 the year when this is true

Using the IF function together with the date functions are now working for me.

My query is

```
Select a.OrderAccount 
,a.InvoiceAccount
,a.InvoiceDate
,year(a.InvoiceDate) as Year
,month(a.InvoiceDate) as Month,
Case month(a.InvoiceDate) 
WHEN '11' THEN '1' -- increase year by +1 
WHEN '12' THEN '2'-- increase year by +1 
WHEN '1' THEN '3' 
WHEN '2' THEN '4'
WHEN '3' THEN '5'
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Make a table with the fiscal periods. Join and compare the dates. Then you can use the fiscal periods table whenever you need it in a query.

Comment: Aside: Curious thing that your `case` expression uses string values for everything other than `month(a.InvoiceDate)`. Based on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) each `when` value will be converted to an integer before comparison. The `then` values will remain strings. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) to just add 2 months to the original date:

```
MONTH(DATEADD(month,2,a.InvoiceDate)) as FiscalMonth,
YEAR(DATEADD(month,2,a.InvoiceDate)) AS FiscalYear,
```

Answer (score 1):

Create and populate a [Calendar Table](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/) (it makes working with dates much easier).

```
create table Calendar
(
    id int primary key identity,
    [date] datetime,
    [day] as datepart(day, [date]) persisted,
    [month] as datepart(month, [date]) persisted,
    [year] as datepart(year, [date]) persisted,

    day_of_year as datepart(dayofyear, [date]) persisted,
    [week] as datepart(week, [date]),

    day_name as datename(dw, [date]),

    is_weekend as case when datepart(dw, [date]) = 7 or datepart(dw, [date]) = 1 then 1 else 0 end,

    [quarter] as datepart(quarter, [date]) persisted
    --etc...    

)

--populate the calendar

declare @date datetime
set @date = '1-1-2000'

while @date <= '12-31-2100'
begin

   insert Calendar select @date
   set @date = dateadd(day, 1, @date)

end
```

Then, create a `FiscalYear` view:

```
create view FiscalYear
as
    select 

        id, 

        case when month = 11 or month = 12 then year + 1 else year end as [year]


    from Calendar
```

So, whenever you need the fiscal year of a given date, just use something like the following query:

```
select C.*, FY.year fiscal_year from Calendar C inner join FiscalYear FY on FY.id = C.id
```

Of course, since fiscal year is just a computation on a column, you could also just make it a part of the calendar table itself. Then, it's simply:

```
select * from Calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with arithmetic: The fiscal month is `( Month( a.InvoiceDate ) + 1 ) % 12 + 1` and the value to add to the calendar year to get the fiscal year is `Month( a.InvoiceDate ) / 11`.

The following code demonstrates 12 months:

```
with Months as (
  select 1 as M
  union all
  select M + 1
    from Months
    where M < 12 )
  select M, ( M + 1 ) % 12 + 1 as FM, M / 11 as FYOffset
    from Months;
```

D Stanley's answer makes your intention clearer, always a consideration for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this logic in 10 different places and the logic changes starting (say) on 1/1/2018 you will have a mess on your hands.

Create a function that has the logic and then use the function like:

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, dbo.FiscalPeriod(InvoiceDate) AS FP
FROM ...
```

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FiscalPeriod(@InvoiceDate DateTime)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @FiscalDate DateTime

    SET @FiscalDate = DATEADD(month, 2, @InvoiceDate)

    RETURN YEAR(@FiscalDate) * 100 + MONTH(@FiscalDate)
END
```

This returns values like 201705, but you could have dbo.FiscalPeriodMonth() and dbo.FiscalPeriodYear() if you needed. And you can have as complicated logic as you need in one place.